# Showing only relative paths in the directory pane of a Motif FileSelectionBox

Tags: c, motif

What is the recommended way to make an (Open)Motif `XmFileSelectionBox` show just relative paths inside the "Directories" pane? I mean, something like this

[image: desired result with relative paths]

instead of

[image]

I've tried [looking for something](http://www.s-and-b.ru/syshlp/motif_guide/MotifRefGuide/XmFileSeleA.html) tweakable via `.Xresources` but couldn't find anything... Should I write my own [dirSearchProc](http://www.s-and-b.ru/syshlp/motif_guide/MotifRefGuide/XmFileSeleA.html#XmNdirSearchProc) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there is [a resource](http://www.ist.co.uk/motif/books/vol6A/ch-6.fm.html#440574) after all:

```
*pathMode: path_mode_relative
```

(This splits the "Filter" textfield into two "Directory" and "Filter" fields though)